# what does Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in /home/XXX/public_html/feedback2.php on line 180 mean?

Tags: php, forms, scripting, webforms

and how do I find where line 180 is in the code ?

I'm trying to create a PHP feedback form scrip

Comment: Use a decent text editor that shows you the line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It means that there was a double quote that it didn't expect in the code. Decent text editors such as [geany](http://www.geany.org/) show line numbers in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Showing your code would help, but :

- parse error means you have some kind of a syntax error somewhere : basically, you are not respecting PHP's syntax
- the problem seems to be that you have a double-quote that shouldn't be here
- the error is arround line 180 of feedback2.php -- as said by the error message ; depending on the editor/IDE you're using, it should be able to show lines numbers, or you should have a "*go to line #*" feature.

Taking a look between lines 170 and 190 of feedback2.php might be useful ;-)